# Android - info for create a loop pad - music app

Tags: java, android, audio, synchronization

I want to create a music loop pad, something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwBPYwiYp-Y

[image: loop pad 24]

Right now, i am using MediaPlayer to play the sounds. I have a global variable that stores the current time (position) of the first audio that is playing, and when i press another button the corresponding audio file starts playing at the position given by the global variable.

My proble is: the sounds are playing out of sync.

can you give me some help? How can i sync the sounds? like this app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwBPYwiYp-Y

Can you point me some info or tutorials about how to create a loop pad?

Thanks
Richardd

Answer (score 2):

Programming something like this is harder than you think. Here are two things you must do to have the sounds play in sync:

1. Make sure all you sounds are at the same tempo, and are cropped properly - that means that the starting and ending of the sound clip must be exactly on beat - another solution would be to store the starting and ending time for each clip (very easy with OOP)
2. Use a timer to make sure the sound starts playing on beat. For example, if you wanted to make your music run at 120 bpm, you would need to have your timer fire every 500 ms.

Here is some code (only concept, won't compile):

```
Timer beatTimer;
boolean isDrumLoopEnabled;
boolean isDrumLoopCurrentlyPlaying;
Sound drumloop;

public void startMusic(){
    //prepare timer
    beatTimer=new Timer();
    beatTimer.interval=500;//for 120 bpm
    beatTimer.onTick+=onTickHandler;

    isDrumLoopPlaying=false;
    isDrumLoopCurrentlyPlaying=false;

    //load sounds
    Sound drumloop=new Sound("/storage/emulated/drumloop.ogg");

    //start music
    beatTiemr.start();
}

//this method will run on every beat:
public void onTickHandler(){
    if(isDrumLoopEnabled){
        //make sure drum loop isn't already playing
        if(!isDrumLoopCurrentlyPlaying){
            //begin looping drumloop in background
            drumloop.startloop();
            isDrumLoopCurrentlyPlaying=true;
        }
    }else{
        if(isDrumLoopCurrentlyPlaying){
            //stop playing drumloop
            drumloop.stopPlaying();
        }
    }
}

//when the button is pressed...
public void drumloop_buttonpressed(){
    //this will toggle whether to play the drum loop:
    isDrumLoopEnabled=!isDrumLoopEnabled;
}
```